# How to fix environment.getActiveProfiles() is null in UnitTest Java

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, environment-variables

I have a piece of Java code which uses an environment variable and the behaviour of the code depends on the value of this variable.
And then I created the UnitTest of it in TestClass and debug to see the result.

Then I found null from `environment.getActiveProfiles()`

[image]

I set the environment in serviceImpl by this way

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

I've already mocked some environment here in TestClass

```
@Mock
private Environment environment; 
...
...
String[] activeProfiles =  new String[]{"dev"};
ActiveProfilesResponse activeProfilesResponse = new ActiveProfilesResponse();
activeProfilesResponse.setProfiles(List.of(activeProfiles));
when(environment.getActiveProfiles()).thenReturn(activeProfiles);
```

and also provides  `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` in that TestClass

Do I need to add any mock or anything else for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `environment` is null, hence the `NullPointerException`. This means that your mocked `Environment` from the test class is not injected into your test subject class. You haven't shown us the part of your class where `environment` is supposed to be set. But, for example, if it is injected in the constructor, make sure your test class initializes your class with `new YourClass(environment);` and not `new YourClass(null);`.

Comment: Oh you're correct ! Thank you so much .
and Sorry for forgot to show how I set Enviroment in service Class .
So I should use private final with environment in service Class ?
Or I need to inject it in @Before in TestClass ?

Comment: I actually prefer constructor injection over field injection exactly because then it's easier for me to inject whatever I want in test classes. So how about having a constructor like `@Autowired public YourClass(Environment environment) { this.environment = environment; }` and indeed making your environment private and final and removing the `@Autowired` annotation from it? This works just as well as autowiring fields. And if you've got any other autowired fields, set all of them in the constructor the same way too.